# Get older versions of Internet Explorer

Tags: testing-environment, virtualmachine, ie9, ie8, compatibility-testing

How can I get installer for older IE version?

For testing, I often need particular version and have found compatibility mode to not be good. Where is some nice directory of every version? Extra langauage versions are optional. Then how do you run them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like using [modern.ie](https://www.modern.ie/en-us) (by Microsoft) because they carry all IE browsers from IE6 to IE11 and it's free.

You basically choose which version of IE you want and it comes prepackaged with its own virtual machine so you don't have to install anything. Just run and test. The downside is the virtual machines are time limited and expire after a certain amount of time which means you have to re-download and install.

Another option is [SauceLabs](http://www.saucelabs.com) which allows you to run virtualized version of IE through a website (remotely). If you need multiple language versions you might try MSDN.

Comment: Usually there's a command you can run from the command prompt in the VM to reregister the VM and extend the time. I do it so that the VM doesn't always shut down on me. I don't know the command offhand, but it might be something like `slmgr –rearm`, run as an admin

Comment: @TankorSmash Good to know!

Comment: @TankorSmash Yup, that's the one, you need to run it from the Administrative command prompt.

Comment: From the notes on modern.ie, in the pdf: It is also highly recommended that you implement a rollback strategy for any virtual machines that
you download. This could be as simple as holding onto the original archive that you downloaded,
or you could take advantage of your virtualization platform’s snapshotting capability so that you
can start over with a fresh VM at any time and not have to worry about the guest operating system
running out of trial time.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use http://www.browserstack.com/ where you can not only get older versions of IE but pretty much any browser you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try [OldApps](http://www.oldapps.com/category/browsers). They host old versions of all major browsers.